# SOAPUI LoadTest SetupScript

Tags: performance, soapui

Im new to SOAPUI, i am trying to utilize the Setup Script. to Execute a test step before the main load test is ran.

testSuite.testRunner.runTestStepByName("session_Open")

Need to perform this task once on startup. Can this be done? What is the correct way of calling the test step?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["yours-here"].run( null, true )
` or just `testRunner.runTestStepByName("session_Open")`

Comment: thank you ou_ryperd i tried both suggestions above

for both attempts i get
Tue Mar 07 08:23:57 GMT 2023:ERROR:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testSuite for class: Script30